# Como puedo mostrar una imagen de mi base de datos en una pagina de laravel

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, imagen

las imágenes las tengo en una tabla llamada registro y en el campo Imagen de tipo longblob,
todos los datos de mi tabla si se muestran menos las imágenes.
los datos ya los tengo solo son de mostrar nada de extraer del usuario.

nota importante: es la primera vez que uso laravel y gracias por su tiempo.

este es mi controlador

```
class PersonaController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $registro = Registro::all();
        return view('lista', compact('registro'));
    }

    public function detalle($id)
    {
        $registro = Registro::findOrFail($id);
        $datosImagen = $registro->Imagen;
        $registro->Imagen = $datosImagen;

        return view('detalle', compact('registro'));
    }
}
```

y esta mi vista

```
class PersonaController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $registro = Registro::all();
        return view('lista', compact('registro'));
    }

    public function detalle($id)
    {
        $registro = Registro::findOrFail($id);
        $datosImagen = $registro->Imagen;
        $registro->Imagen = $datosImagen;

        return view('detalle', compact('registro'));
    }
}
```